# Eclipse CDT's Content Assist Doesn't Suggest Function Pointers' Expected Parameters

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, content-assist

I'm working on a project that has many many function pointers each with a different set of parameters. Content assist doesn't work with that, that it doesn't provide assistance with the expected list of parameters by this function pointer. Because of this I have to manually look up the definition of the function pointer to figure out what it expects. This really wastes a lot of time!

Is this a bug? Is there a work around it?

Comment: I too am having this problem. Did you find a solution?